# swap first and last value in an array (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

I believe the code works but the tester code isn't and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to swap the first and last value in an array.

```
public class ArrayMethods {

 private int[] values;
 public ArrayMethods(int[] initialValues) {
    values = initialValues;
  }
 public void swapFirstAndLast() {
    int lastvalplace = values.length;
    int firstval = values[0];
    values[0] = values[lastvalplace];
    values[lastvalplace] = firstval;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayMethods initialValues = new ArrayMethods(int[] 50, 32, 4, 9, 2);
     swapFirstAndLast = new swapFirstAndLast(values);
 }

}
```

Comment: *"I believe the code works"* You should test it and be sure, not just assume. Also, what does happen with the "test code"?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? I guess it doesn't even compile, does it?

Comment: the last element in an array is `array[array.length - 1]` (not `array[array.length]` like in your code)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's basic swap + 0-indexed array case.

```
int lastElement = values[values.length-1];
values[values.length-1] = values[0];
values[0] = lastElement;
```

Your code generates `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` which gives a stacktrace which prints you the line in which the problem is and the information that the index is too large. It also gives you the index.

You got something like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26
at ArrayMethods.swapFirstAndLast(ArrayMethods.java:10)
```

Remember, the last element of an array in Java is `array[array.length-1]`

And there is also one problem. Your main:

```
ArrayMethods initialValues = new ArrayMethods(new int[]{50, 32, 4, 9, 2});
initialValues.swapFirstAndLast();
```